# Different outcome of matplotlib localisation depending on the interpreter

Tags: python, matplotlib, terminal, spyder

The same script gives two different formatting variants of the axis depending if the script was executed via the terminal or via spyder.

I tried the following code on a German pc with spyder (localisation is working, decimal points are commas) and python/ipython on the console (localisation is not working, decimal points are points).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['axes.formatter.use_locale'] = True

a=[.1,.2,.3,.4,.5]
b=[.1,.2,.3,.4,.5]

plt.plot(a,b)
plt.show()
```

I would have expected that is get the same result for both variants, so a comma for a decimal point.

Comment: You need to set the locale. Presumably spyder does that for you, but else something like `import locale;
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')`

Comment: Yes, that does the trick if you put it after the import of matplotlib. Thanks, and before closing the stackexchange question: I did not find any hint on your trick in the documentation. Did I overlook it or is it too obvious to be documented? But anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: I guess the point is `use_locale` is assumed to make it clear that it *uses* whatever locale is set. So you need to make sure you *set* some locale at some point.